# Mean number of sixes after rolling 100 dice

Tags: probability

I am currently working through Stowe's *Thermodynamics and Statistical Mechanics* third chapter, titled "Systems with many elements". The first exercise problem is as follows:

> Consider many systems, each having 100 rolled dice. Suppose that we are
> interested in the number of dice per system showing sixes. For these systems,
> calculate (a) the mean number of sixes and (b) the standard deviation about this value.

My first attempt at solving this was to note that the probability of getting $k$ sixes is $P(k \text{ sixes}) = {100 \choose k} \left( \frac{1}{6}\right)^k \left( \frac{5}{6} \right)^{100-k}$. Hence the the average number of sixes rolled is $\bar{k} = \sum_{n=0}^{100}n {100 \choose n} \left( \frac{1}{6}\right)^n \left( \frac{5}{6} \right)^{100-n}$. I opened excel and computed the above equation and obtained $\bar{k} \approx 16.7$.

I checked the solutions at the back of the textbook, and indeed that is the correct answer. However, my worry is that the second exercise requires us to do the same, but this time with systems composed of $10^8$ dice.

Obviously, there is no way I can use excel to do such a calculation, so I am not sure on how I could approximate a solution. I thought about using a Gaussian distribution, but I do not see how I could set it up so it tells me the specific number of sixes rolled. Any ideas?

Comment: Hint: use linearity of expectation

Comment: Are you trying to find the mean and standard deviation of a binomial distribution? Someone else has already calculated them.

Comment: @peterwhy I think you are right. Binomial distribution has a clearly defined expectation. I think I was getting confused by working with the "sixes", but I see now that it is indeed just a good old fashion binomial distribution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are faster ways - the mean of a Bernoulli distribution is $p$ and its variance $p(1-p)$, so the mean of a binomial distribution is $np$ and its variance $np(1-p)$ so its standard deviation is $\sqrt{np(1-p)}$ - but if you want to actually compute the sum then you could try

$$\bar{k} = \sum_{n=0}^{100}n {100 \choose n} \left( \frac{1}{6}\right)^n \left( \frac{5}{6} \right)^{100-n} \\= \sum_{n=1}^{100}n {100 \choose n} \left( \frac{1}{6}\right)^n \left( \frac{5}{6} \right)^{100-n} \\=\sum_{n=1}^{100} \frac{100}{6} {99 \choose n-1} \left( \frac{1}{6}\right)^{n-1} \left( \frac{5}{6} \right)^{(100-1)-(n-1)} \\=\frac{100}{6}\sum_{m=0}^{99}  {99 \choose m} \left( \frac{1}{6}\right)^{m} \left( \frac{5}{6} \right)^{99-m} \\ = \frac{100}{6} \left(\frac16 + \frac56\right)^{99}\\= \frac{100}{6}.$$

Answer (score 4):

Let $X_i$ denote the random variable which takes value 1 if the $i^{th}$ die showed a 6 (with probability 1/6) and takes value 0 if it didn't (with probability 5/6).

The number of dice which showed 6 is $Y = \sum_{i=1}^{100} X_i$, by definition.

The *expected* number of dice which showed 6 is $\mathbb{E}[Y] = \sum_{i=1}^{100} \mathbb{E}[X_i]$

From the definition of $X_i$, $\mathbb{E}[X_i] = {1 \over 6} \times 1 + {5 \over 6} \times 0 = {1 \over 6}$

Putting it all together, $\mathbb{E}[Y] = 100/6$

Bottomline, you don't need to compute the distribution to compute the expected value